# A formula for the real part of the product of two complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I have found the following in a paper and I can't see how it is achieved:
$$
    e^{\operatorname{Re}(s\ln u)} = e^{\operatorname{Re}(s)\ln{|u|}-\operatorname{Im}(s)\operatorname{Arg}(u)}
$$
where $u,s \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: What is $s$ ?..

Comment: $s \in \mathbb{C}$ hence the $\text{Re}(s)$ and $\text{Im}(s)$. I thought it was implied, not sure it warranted a down vote but thanks for the constructive feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u$ is a complex variable, the complex logarithm of $u$ is defined as

$\ln (u) = \ln (|u|)+ i\arg(u)$

where $\ln (|u|)$ is the real natural logarithm of the real value $|u|$.

Now, assuming $s\in \Bbb{C}$, write $s=Re(s)+iIm(s)$

Therefore, $$s \ln (u) = (Re(s)+iIm(s))(\ln (|u|)+ i\arg(u))$$
$$= Re(s)\ln(|u|)+iRe(s)\arg(u)+iIm(s)\ln(|u|)-Im(s)\arg(u)$$

Taking the real part of $Re(s \ln (u))=Re(s)\ln(|u|)-Im(s)\arg(u)$

As desired.

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer is probably the simplest to follow through at a glance. Is the identity you defined for $ln(u)$ simply one that is learned?

Answer (score 1):

Let , $s=s_1+is_2\in \mathbb C$. Also , $\ln u=\ln |u|+i\arg(u)$.

Then , $s\ln u=(s_1\ln|u|-s_2\arg u)+i(s_1\arg u+s_2\ln |u|)$.

So , $\Re(s\ln u)=s_1\ln |u|-s_2\arg u=\Re(s)\ln|u|-\Im(s)\arg(u)$.